# Shell/Bash - send cli command until desired value returned

Tags: bash, shell

My script needs to run `aws cli` command until getting `success` status. The below script doesn't work and throws a syntax error. I'm aiming also to get it re-try CLI call until it gets `successful` up to (for example) 5 retires:

`[0: command not found`

Big thanks to @Ярослав Рахматуллин!!

```
retry_times=5
counter=0

ri_status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=replication-instance-arn,Values=$ri_arn --query=Connections[0].Status --region us-east-1`

#test $ri_status = '"successful"'
#echo $?

#until test $ri_status = '"successful"'
until [[ $ri_status =~ successful ]]
    do 
    ri_status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=replication-instance-arn,Values=$ri_arn --query=Connections[0].Status --region us-east-1`
    [[ counter -eq $retry_times ]] && echo "Failed!" && exit 1
    echo "Trying again. Try #$counter"
    ((counter++))
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: look into https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

Comment: You should move away from the `` syntax and adopt the `$(command)`.

Comment: backticks work just fine. there is no technical reason for removing them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
until [ $? -eq 0 ]
do
    # foobar...
    sleep 5
done
```

notice the spaces. [ and ] are separate commands and need spaces around them do be distinguishable from other commands. `0]` is confusing to bash, so is `[0` which is "["+"0".

Just test for the condition that you want directly instead of looking at the exit value of the previous command.

```
until test $ri_status = '"successful"'
do
    ri_status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=replication-instance-arn,Values=$ri_arn --query=Connections[0].Status --region us-east-1`
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Do I need to re-establish the entire cli command in `do; ri_status`?

Comment: yes. it will not update / produce new output unless you run it again.

Comment: i'm not sure about the '"successful"' , a safer match would be `[[ $ri_status =~ successful ]]` instead of test = ....

Comment: How to add max retires attempts? I want the script to try `ri_status` n-times and when that fails to `break` and `echo` error message.

Comment: Added retries number.

Comment: `[[ $ri_status =~ successful ]]` throws error `test: too many arguments`

Comment: instead of test. not after test.

Comment: Consider reading https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html and https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238790/discussion-between-marcin2x4-and--).